# How do I avoid removal from Play Store due to copyright infringement?

Tags: copyright

I made a simple Batman puzzle game using some Batman posters from the internet. There are apps on Google Play Store and Windows Phone Store that also feature these kind of Batman pictures, but they haven't been removed. My app was removed from the Play Store because of this copyright thing.

How do I publish my app to stores without copyright issues?

Comment: What you are describing is copyright infringement. Those others just haven't been caught.

Answer (score 15):

> There are apps on Google Play Store and Windows Phone Store that also feature these kind of Batman pictures.

You probably just had less luck than them, or intended to make profit on your app. By what you stated, you also used "posters" which are pictures that can be easily spotted by a bot.

I know that will not be helpful, but if you don't want your app to be removed from the store for such reason, you have two choices:

- **Don't use copyrighted content or characters**
- **Contact the right holders to buy a license on their copyrighted content.**

By commiting such copyright infrigments, you risk serious trials or even worse, to get a lifetime ban for your developer account. Be careful!